# Running Petrel in Virtual Machine?

Tags: ocean, petrel

Does anyone run Petrel in a VM? Parallels Workstation Extreme looks like it would do the trick, but I'm wondering if the new RemoteFX in Windows Server's Hyper-V would work?

Feel free to make this a Community Wiki post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are actually using internally Hyper-V to install Petrel on different operation systems. So to answer your question : yes it works.

In other words, there is nothing in Petrel that would stop you from using virtual machine boxes.

Answer (score 2):

Petrel does not provide an official support for virtual machines or remote desktops. However it's true that Petrel team uses virtual machines a lot in their internal developments. Not only Hyper-V, but also VMWare, Windows Virtual PC etc. It works *most of the time*, but sometimes you might get a trouble with 3D visualization (especially in large 3D volume visualization, making the most of your graphics card), or an issue with accessing Petrel plug-ins binaries and/or data over a virtual network connection. Such issues are hard to discover and sometimes even harder to fix, but again, in many cases it just works out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

We are using ESXI and everything works fine. Sometimes we have a problems with plug-ins which required additional SW, or have some specific requirement for graphic.